# IIS Rewrite conditions rule is not working

Tags: url, iis, mod-rewrite

First thankyou anyone , Engilsh is not my native language
But this problem is very difficult for me

I need
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/index.php?id=image01`
to
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/image01`

and if the users enter `http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/image01` on address bar
the website is can work

I think the rules is
users can input those
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/image01`
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/index.php?id=image01`

1.
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/index.php?id=image01`
Redirect like this `http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/image01` and go to rule2
Rewrite `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={C:1}" />`

2.
`http://xxxx.show.bis.tw/event_register/image01`
just only Rewrite `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={C:1}" />`

my code is
if file and directory do Redirect or Rewrite website will broken (css/js/image)

I try to rule>1 and rule>2 write in one rule but it not work
I don't know how to fix it

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            // 1
            <rule name="025" stopProcessing="true">
                 <match url=".*" />
                 <conditions>    // file and directory not Redirect|Rewrite
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            // 2
            <rule name="026">
                <match url="index\.php(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            // 3
            <rule name="027" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="/index.php?id=" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

thankyou anyone very thank
I almost tow days can't not sleep just fix this

Comment: Try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-85) to get detailed error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rewritemaps instead of rules in your web.config file?

```html
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="rewrites">
            <add key="/event_register/image01" value="/event_register/index.php?id=image01" />            
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```